# 500 error when converting svn repository to mercurial

Tags: svn, mercurial, migration

I'm trying to convert a Subversion repository to Mercurial.

This is what I've done:

Followed the instructions [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebInIisOnWindows), [here](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/mercurial-on-iis7/) and [here](http://www.endswithsaurus.com/2010/05/setting-up-and-configuring-mercurial-in.html), and:

- installed TortoiseHg 2.9.2 (with Mercurial 2.7.2)
- installed Python 2.7 (not Python 2.6 like the link says)
- used paths instead of collections as specified [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) to denote the repositories:
- set up a web server to host repository (ensuring that the CgiModule was installed via Server Manager)

Set up a Mercurial repository in C:\MyRepository

Ensured that in C:\MyRepository\.hg\hgrc file, I added

```
[extensions]
convert =
```

Typed in `C:\MyRepository>hg convert http://www.myrepository.org:8080/svn --debug --traceback`

I got this output:

```
assuming destination svn-hg
initializing destination svn-hg repository
svn: cannot probe remote repository, assume it could be a subversion repository. Use --source-type if you know better
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hgext\convert\subversion.pyo", line 264, in __init__
  File "hgext\convert\transport.pyo", line 89, in __init__
  File "libsvn\client.pyo", line 1845, in svn_client_open_ra_session
SubversionException: ("Repository moved permanently to 'http://myrepository.org:8080/'; please relocate",
5011)
using http://myrepository.org:8080/svn
sending capabilities command
real URL is http://myrepository.org:8080/
requested URL: 'http://myrepository.org:8080/svn?cmd=capabilities'
sending between command
sending capabilities command
requested URL: 'http://myrepository.org:8080/?cmd=capabilities'
capabilities: none
requested URL: 'http://myrepository.org:8080/?cmd=between&pairs=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-
0000000000000000000000000000000000000'
http authorization required
realm: VisualSVN Server
user: tolao
password:
http auth: user tolao, password *********
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 97, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 778, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 549, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 869, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 840, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 775, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 507, in check
  File "hgext\convert\__init__.pyo", line 283, in convert
  File "hgext\convert\convcmd.pyo", line 497, in convert
  File "hgext\convert\convcmd.pyo", line 56, in convertsource
  File "hgext\convert\hg.pyo", line 241, in __init__
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 112, in repository
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 102, in _peerorrepo
  File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 245, in instance
  File "mercurial\statichttprepo.pyo", line 159, in instance
  File "mercurial\statichttprepo.pyo", line 106, in __init__
  File "mercurial\scmutil.pyo", line 823, in readrequires
  File "mercurial\scmutil.pyo", line 223, in read
  File "mercurial\statichttprepo.pyo", line 42, in read
IOError: [Errno None] HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
abort: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Any idea why I got the '500 internal server error' at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mercurial convert extension you're using says you should use `svnsync` to sync the full svn history local and to convert from that.  Converting from a local source would avoid this (since that 500 comes from your remote server which would be out of the picture) and saves a lot of overall time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on how I would 'svnsync to sync the full svn history local'. Can you please explain this?

Comment: svnsync is a tool from subversion that mirrors entire repositories from remote locations to local.  You run that tool to take your remote svn repository and create a complete copy locally -- then Mercurial will chew through it on convert: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt

Comment: In the end, I decided to do the conversion on the server rather than doing it on a client. In other words, I created a folder called C:\MyRepo on the same machine that the svn repository was located; typed hg init C:\MyRepo to set up a Mercurial repository there, then from the command line at C:\MyRepo, typed hg convert C:\LocationOfOldSvnRepo. Your emphasis on local source gave the right idea.

Comment: Good deal.  Local disk always beats network when you're doing a one time bulk data processing task.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the URL you enter is incorrect. Double-check whether you enter correct URL to Subversion repository. It should be `http://www.myrepository.org/svn/<repo-name>`.